# Scss files not working or load in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new learner of Laravel- in my project 'style.scss' not working.
Here is my path public/css/style.scss how to use it.

My slider button not working without style.scss files in Laravel, how resolve this problem.
Please give me suggestion how to import style.scss file in welcome.blade files.
Thank you

Comment: scss files need to be compiled into css files. Nowadays in Laravel this is done with vite ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#main-content)). Older projects may use [mix](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mix)

Answer (score 0):

You must set app.scss in vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

and then import all your scss file in app.scss
then compile your scss to css by "npm run build"
and include it in main view template file.